# Distance calculation API

Tags: apex, api, httpcalloutmock

Below is the code for distance calculation using matrix api. I have declared all the variables as private and called HTTP get method for this. in the log of the code I got an error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getdistance() from
>   the type System.HttpResponse.

how can i prevent this error

```
public class test {

private static final String OriginAddress = 'Origin_Address__c';
private static final String OriginCity = 'Origin_City__c';
private static final String OriginState = 'Origin_State__c';
private static final String OriginCountry = 'Origin_Country__c';
private static final Integer OriginZipcode = 0;
private static final String DestinationAddress = 'Destination_Address__c';
private static final String Destinationcity = 'Destination_City__c';
private static final String DestinationCountry = 'Destination_Country__c';
private static final String DestinationState = 'Destination_State__c';
private static final Integer DestinationZipcode = 0;
private static final Integer TravelTime = 0;
private static final String ModeofTravel = 'Mode_of_Travel__c';

private decimal getdistance (){
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod('GET');

     String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json'
        + '?origins=' + OriginAddress + OriginCity + OriginCountry + OriginState + OriginZipcode
        + '&destinations=' + DestinationAddress + Destinationcity + DestinationCountry + DestinationState + DestinationZipcode
        + '?&mode=' + ModeofTravel
        + '?arrival_time=' + TravelTime
        + '&sensor=false'
        + '&language=en'
        + '&units=imperial';

            req.setEndPoint(url);
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            return res.getdistance();
        }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in last line of your method -

```
Decimal distance = Decimal.valueOf(res.getBody());
return distance;
```

Error was coming because return type is decimal but actually it is returing res.getBody() of string type.

Comment: It's working now, but the field distance__c was not updated with the value

Answer (score 2):

When you call the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) you will receive a JSON as response as below.

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361993
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 52 mins",
                  "value" : 13943
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

You have to parse the JSON to extract the distance details. You can either use JSONParser or JSON Deserialization to do that.

Here is an example of how to do it by JSON Deserialization.

You have to create a Wrapper class for the response. You can use [Json2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) for this.

**WrapperClass**

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class DistanceWrapper {

    public class Elements {
        public Distance distance;
        public Distance duration;
        public String status;
    }

    public class Distance {
        public String text;
        public Integer value;
    }

    public List<String> destination_addresses;
    public List<String> origin_addresses;
    public List<Rows> rows;
    public String status;

    public class Rows {
        public List<Elements> elements;
    }


    public static DistanceWrapper parse(String json) {
        return (DistanceWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, DistanceWrapper.class);
    }
}
```

**JSON Deserialization**

```
String json = '{'+
'   \"destination_addresses\" : [ \"New York, NY, USA\" ],'+
'   \"origin_addresses\" : [ \"Washington, DC, USA\" ],'+
'   \"rows\" : ['+
'      {'+
'         \"elements\" : ['+
'            {'+
'               \"distance\" : {'+
'                  \"text\" : \"225 mi\",'+
'                  \"value\" : 361993'+
'               },'+
'               \"duration\" : {'+
'                  \"text\" : \"3 hours 52 mins\",'+
'                  \"value\" : 13943'+
'               },'+
'               \"status\" : \"OK\"'+
'            }'+
'         ]'+
'      }'+
'   ],'+
'   \"status\" : \"OK\"'+
'}';
DistanceWrapper obj = DistanceWrapper.parse(json);
DistanceWrapper.Rows row = (DistanceWrapper.Rows)obj.rows.get(0);
DistanceWrapper.Elements elem = (DistanceWrapper.Elements)row.elements.get(0);
DistanceWrapper.Distance dist = (DistanceWrapper.Distance)elem.distance;
String distMile = dist.text;
Integer distKM = dist.value;
System.debug('distMile'+distMile);
System.debug('distKM'+distKM);
```

You will get the values.

Comment: for this wrapper class should I write a VF page to update the values?

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: After writing the wrapper class does the distance field gets updated automatically or should I write another code to update the field.